# angular viewportScroller capturing events ending up with incompatible types

Tags: angular

I am trying to use this example from the Angular docs to implement scroll for when you navigate back:

```
class AppModule {
  constructor(router: Router, viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) {
    router.events.pipe(filter((e: Event): e is Scroll => e instanceof Scroll)).subscribe(e => {
      if (e.position) {
        // backward navigation
        viewportScroller.scrollToPosition(e.position);
      } else if (e.anchor) {
        // anchor navigation
        viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(e.anchor);
      } else {
        // forward navigation
        viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
      }
    });
  }
```

But I end up with this error when compiling:

```
 ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(23,24): error TS2345: Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<Event>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Event, Event>'.
      Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
        Type 'import("/Users/PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable<import("/Users/PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/@angular/router/router").Event>' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable<Event>'.
          Type 'import("/Users/PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/@angular/router/router").Event' is not assignable to type 'Event'.
            Type 'ActivationEnd' is missing the following properties from type 'Event': bubbles, cancelBubble, cancelable, composed, and 18 more.
    src/app/app.module.ts(23,48): error TS2677: A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
      Type 'Scroll' is missing the following properties from type 'Event': bubbles, cancelBubble, cancelable, composed, and 18 more.
    src/main.ts(4,10): error TS2305: Module '"./app/app.module"' has no exported member 'AppModule'.
```

Comment: Could you change your filter part to the below format and see if it works:
Replace : router.events.pipe(filter((e: Event): e is Scroll => e instanceof Scroll))
With       : router.events.pipe(filter((e): e is Scroll => e instanceof Scroll))

Comment: yep that fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing (e: Event) to just (e) works.

`Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<Event>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Event, Event>'.`

I guess there are two different types of events, and what the filter is receiving is not the same type of Event that the router.events has in it.

Not declaring the type received resolves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this: (e: RouterEvent | Scroll): e is Scroll

Comment: Please consider adding explanation and using ` to format your answer better